# Input not accepted by fields

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a website where I want to run the complete process of cart functionality. All goes well until I click on Payment method and select Debit card and.While putting data in field it doesn't accept. How can I put data into fields. Here is the link of Website to be tested: https://vapesuite.allomate.solutions/#/ . Below is the code to input data into the fields.

```
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]")));
System.out.println("We have selected Credit card method");
Thread.sleep(5000);

WebElement debitCreditCardButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Debit or Credit Card']")));
debitCreditCardButton.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
        
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)");
//Here is the problem, the below path not working   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id="credit-card-number"]"))).sendKeys("4111111111111111");
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of error: https://prnt.sc/1670u4y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are nested iframes :

card number looks to be in

```
div[id^='zoid-paypal-card-fields-uid_']
```

iframe.

**use this code  :**

```
debitCreditCardButton.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("div[id^='zoid-paypal-card-fields-uid_']")));
// and then send keys to card number input field. 

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("credit-card-number"))).sendKeys("4111111111111111");
```

Comment: I try your code but it shows the error: https://prnt.sc/1672u50

Comment: my bad ! instead use this css `iframe[name^='__zoid__paypal_card_fields__']` in place of `div[id^='zoid-paypal-card-fields-uid_']`

Comment: I think  `iframe[name^='__zoid__paypal_card_fields__']` in again inside `//iframe[contains(@name, 'zoid__paypal_buttons')]` so there no point to do `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` - remove this and then try

Comment: @Zaman10 :  I can not reply to you. That thread does not allow me to type anything

Comment: I have sent you an invite to chat. can you please available for a chat on StackOverflow?

Comment: I can not reply on that chat, because the question is closed. try creating a new ticket instead

Comment: @Zaman10  : give me your mail id. they will close the ticket if you do not provide them code, error stack trace and HTML